# How to curl a page that need login first

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Here is the login page:

```
http://www.ifreewind.net/iFreeWind.aspx
```

I need content of this page which need login first:

```
http://www.ifreewind.net/Users/Search.aspx?R=1&P=00102&i=2
```

On case you need, my post data content is here:

```
$data = "__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE3NjQ3MDc3NDQPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAQUSUmVtZW1iZXJNZUNoZWNrQm94r57YdIUtbSps%2FGLW1PUtjxcILdE%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQLKivfjBgLw2N3fDgLC9%2FChAwLxuKbKAgL%2BjNCfDwU6DJjH4Q2acTlGVXmDrSv2Nn4G&UserNameTextBox=myemailaddress%40gmail.com&PasswordTextBox=mypassword&LoginButton=%E7%99%BB%E9%99%86";
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

My code is here, but not work:

```
$site = "http://www.ifreewind.net/Users/Search.aspx?R=1&P=00102&i=2";
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('Host:www.ifreewind.net',
        'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1',
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language:zh-cn,zh;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Charset:GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'Referer:http://www.ifreewind.net/Users/Search.aspx?R=1&P=00102&i=2',
        'Cookie:Hm_lvt_7fa3bcf45d96b91c6a87d1433c045849=1327324205986; VisitUrl_-1=ok; ASP.NET_SessionId=4smyrujt3m3cnu2sxbh55z55; Hm_lpvt_7fa3bcf45d96b91c6a87d1433c045849=1327324205986; MyId=7087; iTechAuthen=FDDE38649ADA11A5C73923D4D9437097226833721D48739F39720A91C49A95DCC345C8E9DE670B71D837808619CBF23213C6252AE82112A06CE37271D7D1A3466979E2B264845C8C75B7E1791DDB49C910178DA0BC6D5BD4D6AC536842279D41FA2866DA5B4F278BAB6443D2F370B96F1E5723C685AA015BE611317F40F66965DD2CF0FD5E7C1DB794D7172CC784EF1C2B773CFCAE05772EE611B6F82EF6894F8B32EA932D01F81F70F73C18F1CB8C6F3DDC5E44',
        'Cache-Control:max-age=0'
        );


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);//add

ob_start();
return curl_exec($ch);

ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);
```

Actually my code will meet strange results in web browser like a lot of "����ܰ��", I tried to switch language charset in firefox, but utf-8 and others just doest't show well, so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a header parser to get back the PHPSESSID. This makes for cleaner future curl requests. Heres an example.
This was part of some object oriented programming where I could CURL into different parts of the site, and send my sessionID to track the session.

```
function login($email,$password){
$login=false;
$post='member[email]='.urlencode($email).'&member[password]='.urlencode($password);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://signon.page/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//POST
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,4);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$output=curl_exec($ch);

//get cookies in map array
$rows=explode("\n",$output);
foreach($rows as $num=>$row){
$trim=substr($row,0,5);
$trim2=substr($row,0,29);
if ($trim2=="Location: /public/member/home")$login=true;
/*  if the site sends back a header redirect my login worked.*/
if ($trim=="Set-C") {$rownum=$num;}}
$cookies=$rows[$rownum];
$cookies=substr($cookies,12);/*RAW COOKIE*/
$cookies=explode("; ",$cookies);
$arr=array();
foreach ($cookies as $n=>$v){
$s=explode("=",$v);
$arr[$s[0]]=$s[1];}
$cookies=$arr;

$_SESSION['SN']=$cookies['PHPSESSID'];
curl_close($ch);
$_SESSION['auth']=$login;
return $login;}//end isLoggedIn
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched a whole day about PHPSESSID, but still confused about it. So the code I still not throroughly understand. Maybe I should buy a book.

Comment: Pardon my lack of indentation for now